# Apple starts rejecting my app for missing NSContactsUsageDescription

Tags: ios, app-store, zoom-sdk, info-plist

I am using a library (Zoom Meeting SDK) to develop my iOS application that can perform several tasks.
One of them requires access to contacts, but I am not using this specific functionality in my app.

Unfortunately Apple starts rejecting my app with the following error:

> ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “MyApp.app” bundle should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.

How can I avoid this issue?

I have temporarily added the NSContactsUsageDescription to my beta app’s Info.plist file to continue my testing, but this is not a real solution for the release version as I cannot give a good reason for this permission request. My app does not use contacts in any way.
Bear in mind that Apple could ask me to provide a way to test it, or to provide a video showing how my app uses Contacts.

So it is a blocking issue for releasing a new version of my app.

Is there anything similar to

> user-permission remove

that can be used in the Android app manifest for an iOS app?

```
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SPECIFIC_PERMISSION"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: Just say the truth: you are using a library that requires this access, even though you will not (directly) make use of that access.

Comment: I can try... Typically, Apple tends to be less than relaxed when reviewing an application.

Comment: You could lie instead; can't imagine that would make them more relaxed if they found out.

Comment: Identify what legitimate purpose Zoom has for requesting access and construct the description from that. But the app store review historically rejects messages like “because such-and-such API requires it”. It has too be worded in a way that Apple can see that end user can understand what (potential) app functionality is enabled by granting access (e.g., “to show list of people to invite to video call”), even if you don’t use that functionality in your app (yet). Needless to say, if you never call the API that actually requests that permission, that alert will never be presented in your app.